# How to exclude specific file types from the following .htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with excluding .xml sitemap from adding the trailing slash Rule.

here's the htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

#www to non
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?ghadaalsaman\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,NE,L]

#index redirect 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]

# add a trailing slash to non files
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# add html internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ $1.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thanks for @anubhava for your Help

Comment: Try this rule RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /index.html?sitemap=1 [L] add it above #www to non

Comment: Same problem, Thanks for your attempt

Answer (score 2):

i've solved it by adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sitemap [NC]
```